# Characteristic of $3\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z} \times 5\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the characteristic of $3\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z} \times 5\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times  \mathbb{Z}_3$. Need a confirm for my solutions:

$\bullet$ $\text{char}(3\mathbb{Z}) = 0$

$\bullet$ $\text{char}(\mathbb{Z} \times 5\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ because both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $5\mathbb{Z}$ have characteristic $0$.

$\bullet$ $\text{char}(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times  \mathbb{Z}_3)=15$ because they are finite rings with order $5$ and $3$ and $(5,3) = 1$.

Thanks

Comment: @Arthur Rings, right? I've edited the main post thx

Comment: $3\mathbb{Z}$ does not have a multiplicative identity, so characteristic does not make sense for it.

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal you're right, because the "unity" of $\mathbb{Z}$ became $3$ in this new ring. Thanks for let me see this!

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z} \times 5\mathbb{Z}$ also does not have a multiplicative identity. Your solution for $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ is indeed correct (by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You intuitions are right. But according to  definition,

- there is no $n$ so that $n \cdot 3=0$
- there is no $n$ so that $n \cdot(1,5)=(0,0)$
- For all $(a,b) \in \Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_3$, $$15.(a,b)=(0,0)$$

where $n \cdot a=\underbrace{a+a+\cdots+a}_{n\;\text{summands}}$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{More explanation for third:}$

Let $\text{char}(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times  \mathbb{Z}_3)=n$. So,
for all $(a,b) \in \Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_3$ $$n(a,b)=(na,nb)=(0,0). $$
\begin{align}
n(a,b)=(na,nb)=(0,0) &\iff 5\mid na \quad \mbox{and} \quad  3\mid nb\\
                     &\iff 5\mid n  \quad \mbox{and} 3\mid n \ (\mbox{$5$ prime and $5\nmid a$ so $5\mid n$.
 Similar situation is for $3\mid nb$}) \\
                     &\iff n\mid 15
                      &\iff n=15
\end{align}